# Compute P (max(η1, ..., η5) ≤ a) ...

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

If η1, η2, η3, η4, η5 are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with the parameter λ.

---

So far I've done this:

P (max(η1, …, η5) ≤ a) = P (η1 ≤ a  ∩  η2 ≤ a  ∩  η3 ≤ a  ∩  η4 ≤ a  ∩  η5 ≤ a) = P (η1 ≤ a) * P (η2 ≤ a) ... P (η5 ≤ a) = [F(x)]^5

### From here, not sure how to continue the solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco So far I've done this:

P (max(η1, …, η5) ≤ a) = P (η1 ≤ a  ∩  η2 ≤ a  ∩  η3 ≤ a  ∩  η4 ≤ a  ∩  η5 ≤ a) = P (η1 ≤ a) * P (η2 ≤ a) ... P (η5 ≤ a) = [F(x)]^5


From here, not sure how to continue the solution.

Comment: Use the fact that $P[max(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)\leq a] = \prod_{i=1}^{5}{P[x_i \leq a]}$

Comment: @Nicole it should be $[F(a)]^5$ which is the answer.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan do i need to continue after that?

Comment: The result $F(a) = 1-\exp(\lambda a)$ is standard for $\eta \sim \cal{E}(\lambda)$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thank you.

Comment: [It's explicitly encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), so that the system will classify your question as "solved".  A self-answer can attract upvote(s) and increase your reputation.

Comment: @Nicole no that's it. It can't be solved further. You may write it as ${(1-e^{-\lambda x})}^5$. Its just the same thing.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan ok. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Seems to be some possible confusion here: notation, missing minus sign in exponent, etc. // Correct answers on other pages on this site. Note that the max of exponentials is not exponential. By contrast, min of exponentials is exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W = \max(X_1, \dots, X_{5}),$ where $X_i$ are a random sample from
$\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda = 1/\mu$ is a *rate* parameter.

$$F_W(a) = P(W \le a) = P(X_1 \le a) \times \cdots \times P(X_5 \le a) = (1- e^{-\lambda a})^5.$$

PDF can be found by differentiating CDF, but that gets messy with five 
random variables. $E(W) = 1/5\lambda + 1/4\lambda + 1/3\lambda + 1/2\lambda + 1/\lambda =  2.283333/\lambda.$ [Intuitive argument: Suppose $W$ is the waiting for the failure of a parallel system with 5 components, each with failure rate $\lambda.$ The waiting time for
the first failure is $1/5\lambda.$ By the no-memory property of exponentials,
the additional waiting time for the second component to fail is $1/4\lambda,$ and so on.]

Comment: Thank you for your help.